# Can you force netcat to succeed only if all ports in port range succeed?

Tags: linux, netcat

I use `nc` as part of a verification script, and check the output of each `nc` command listed against what the expected output should be.

e.g.,

`nc -zvw1 serv1.host.com 443 | gawk '{print $7}'
Expected output:  succeeded!`

The problem I'm facing is if I want to check a range of ports, while some tests may in fact return `succeeded!`, there's no guarantee that *all* ports returned as such. This is an issue for me because I compare `cmd:output` on a `1:1` basis, based off a configuration file that lists the commands and the expected output.

Instead of listing something like:

`nc -zvw1 serv1.host.com 443 | gawk '{print $7}'
 nc -zvw1 serv1.host.com 444 | gawk '{print $7}'
 nc -zvw1 serv1.host.com 445 | gawk '{print $7}'`

`Expected result: succeeded!
 Expected result: succeeded!
 Expected result: succeeded!`

I'd like to be able to force `nc` to fail if *any* ports in the range fail; so in this case my configuration could be condenced to:

`nc -zvw1 serv1.host.com 443-445 | gawk '{print $7}'
Expected result: succeeded!`

This is a long-winded description of a straight-forward question, unfortunately. Apologies.

Comment: `nc` sets a non-zero return code on error. You should be able to loop through the port numbers you're interested in and just exit with an error the first time `$?` is non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably work:

```
seq 443 445 \
| xargs -n1 sh -c 'nc -zvw1 serv1.host.com $0 >/dev/null 2>&1 || (echo error! && exit 255)' 2>/dev/null \
&& echo succeeded!
```

It basicly emulates port ranges with `seq` and `xargs` and utilizes `nc`'s return value to either `echo error!` and setting `exit 255` to abort `xargs` or `echo succeeded!` when it successfully connected to each given port number.